# Fast delta encoding for increasing sequence of integers in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, compression

Given `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

After encoding, `a' = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, each element represents the difference compare to its previous element.

I know this can be done with

```
for i in range(len(a) - 1, 0, -1):
    a[i] = a[i] - a[i - 1]
```

Is there a faster way? I am working with 2 billion numbers here, the process is taking about 30 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `itertools.starmap`, `islice` and `operator.sub`:

```
from operator import sub
from itertools import starmap, islice

l = list(range(1, 10000000))

[l[0], *starmap(sub, zip(islice(l, 1, None), l))]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, ..., 1]
```

---

Benchmark:

```
l = list(range(1, 100000000))

# OP's method
%timeit [l[i] - l[i - 1] for i in range(len(l) - 1, 0, -1)]    
# 14.2 s ± 373 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# numpy approach by @ynotzort
%timeit np.diff(l)
# 8.52 s ± 301 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# zip approach by @Nick
%timeit [nxt - cur for cur, nxt in zip(l, l[1:])]
# 7.96 s ± 243 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# itertool and operator approach by @Chris
%timeit [l[0], *starmap(sub, zip(islice(l, 1, None), l))]
# 6.4 s ± 255 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This is about 40% faster than the `numpy` and `zip` code at 20M values... (see my note about benchmarking)

Comment: It's interesting that your results show my code outperforming @ynotzort. I wonder if it's related to the amount of memory on each machine.

Comment: @Nick Have you included making the list as a numpy array part (`np.array(l)`)?

Comment: I included that in the setup so it would only run once.

Comment: @Nick For the `numpy` part, converting a list to `numpy.ndarray` takes longer than doing the diff, and I thought it would be a fair comparison to include that conversion into the _timeit_. Perhaps that's where the difference was made.

Comment: That's reasonable; if the original data is in a list you would have to pay that price to do the `diff`. I hadn't realised that was so expensive either.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [numpy.diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), For example:

```py
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
npa = np.array(a)
a_diff = np.diff(npa)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `zip` to put together the list with an offset version and subtract those values

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a[1:] = [nxt - cur for cur, nxt in zip(a, a[1:])]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Out of interest, I ran this, the original code and @ynotzort answer through `timeit` and this was much faster than the `numpy` code for short lists; remaining faster up to about 10M values; both were about 30% faster than the original code. As the list size increased beyond 10M, the `numpy` code has more of a speed up and eventually is faster from about 20M values onward.

**Update**

Also tested the `starmap` code, and that is about 40% faster than the `numpy` code at 20M values...

**Update 2**

@Chris has some more comprehensive performance data in their answer. This answer can be sped up further (about 10%) by using `itertools.islice` to generate the offset list:

```
a = [a[0], *[nxt - cur for cur, nxt in zip(a, islice(a, 1, None))]]
```

Comment: AFAIK, `a[1:]` will create a new list, which may cause a significant overhead if the original list is very large. I've tested your code with `islice` and it becomes as fast as `starmap` approach.

Comment: Interesting, you're right that does improve things significantly. I *love* these type of questions - you learn so much...

Comment: I love it too; it makes you really dig into the codes XD.